# What does "as he's marching" mean?

Tags: grammar

> The army of Charles XII is a hundred thousand strong
>
> As he's marching through smoke
>
> On his road so long

What does "as he's marching" mean? Does it mean that the army is marching with him (Charles XII) through smoke? I'm a little bit confused...

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently a quote from a traditional Swedish military cadence song for marching troops.  The reference is to King Charles XII of Sweden; "his long road", a reference to his campaign against Russia in the early 1700s.  And yes, "as he's marching" means he's leading his army through the smoke of battle.